# Java Map with multiple keys

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I need to create a map, with 3 columns: 2 keys, and 1 value. So each value will contain 2 keys of different classtypes, and can be fetched by using either one. But my problem is that HashMap/Map supports only 1 key, and 1 value. Is there a way to create something like `Map<Key1, Key2, Value>` instead of `Map<Key, Value>`? so `Value` can be fetched by either using its `Key1` or `Key2`.

I apologize if it is a duplicate or a bad question, but I couldn't find a similar one on Stack Overflow.

P.S: I don't want to create 2 maps: `Map<Key1, Value>` and `Map<Key2, Value>` nor creating nested maps I am looking for a multikey table, just one like above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Is there a data structure that works like a multimap but accepts duplicate keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968003/java-is-there-a-data-structure-that-works-like-a-multimap-but-accepts-duplicate)

Comment: I don't believe there is an existing data structure which will do what you want.  You would have to write your own.

Comment: Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is essentially a `Map<T, Map<K, V>>` you can also check out the [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: I think you're referring to Guava's `Table`, not `Multimap`.

Comment: You might need to elaborate why two maps is _not_ an acceptable solution.  Without further details, encapsulating two such maps in a new class is how I'd naively solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the value twice:

```
Map<Object, Value> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key1, someValue);
map.put(key2, someValue);
```

The thing is, it doesn't really matter what type the key is, so use a generic bound that allows both key types - `Object` is fine.

Note that the parameter type of [`Map#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method is just `Object` anyway, so from a look-up perspective there's no value in having separate maps (the type of the key is only relevant for [`put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V))).

Comment: Ok, I'll just do 2 maps. Thanks

Comment: As long as one doesn't need type safety of the specific `Key1` and `Key2` generic type variables, this is a good solution.

Comment: @victor I would **not** use two maps. Having to look up both maps is a waste of your time, code and CPU cycles, AFAICT without benefit. It's the value type of a map that matters. Note that the parameter type of the `get` method of `Map` is `Object`!

Comment: The type of the map key might matter if one expects to use some APIs like `keySet()` or `entrySet()`, but without a stated use case it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to have to write a custom implementation of a map-like class to implement this.  I agree with @William Price above, the easiest implementation will be to simply encapsulate two Map instances.  Be careful using the Map interface, as they rely on equals() and hashCode() for key identity, which you intend to break in your contract.

Answer (score 2):

Write class with your requirements by yourself:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MMap<Key, OtherKey, Value> {

    private final Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<OtherKey, Value> otherMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(Key key, OtherKey otherKey, Value value) {
        if (key != null) { // you can change this, if you want accept null.
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        if (otherKey != null) {
            otherMap.put(otherKey, value);
        }
    }

    public Value get(Key key, OtherKey otherKey) {
        if (map.containsKey(key) && otherMap.containsKey(otherKey)) {
            if (map.get(key).equals(otherMap.get(otherKey))) {
                return map.get(key);
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError("Collision. Implement your logic.");
            }
        } else if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.get(key);
        } else if (otherMap.containsKey(otherKey)) {
            return otherMap.get(otherKey);
        } else {
            return null; // or some optional.
        }
    }

    public Value getByKey(Key key) {
        return get(key, null);
    }

    public Value getByOtherKey(OtherKey otherKey) {
        return get(null, otherKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Apache Commons Collection multi map interface?
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at guava's Table collection that can be used in your context

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html

```
 Table<String,String,String> ==> Map<String,Map<String,String>>
```